# 2 сетевые карты настройка одновременной работы lan и internet

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, lan, ethernet

Windows 10 при активных двух сетевых картах работает тоько интернет по отдельности работают обе
Приоритезация метрикой не работает

Вот таблица маршрутиации 10.191.43.64 локальная сеть, 192.168.10.167 интернет
пробовал мостовое соединение результат тот же
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шлюз по умолчанию должен быть только на той карте, через которую идёт доступ в Инет. На второй - удалить шлюз (и DNS-серверы) в настройках.

Comment: и какой шлюз там указывать?

Comment: НИКАКОГО. Шлюз - это адрес, куда слать пакет, если ни один другой (частный) маршрут не подходит. И вполне естественно, что такой адрес должен быть один, а не два.

Comment: изменил, теперь на локальной сети неопознаная сеть и на интернетовской "Сеть 6, Неопознанная сеть"